# Can I combine these two Linq queries

Tags: join, linq-to-objects

I am trying to combine SharePoint data with a legacy database data and I can get the data, but I need to do it in two queries.    Here are the two Linq queries:

```
 var query = 
            (from dtEai in result.AsEnumerable()
             join allAP in dtAllAirports.AsEnumerable() 
             on dtEai.Field<int>("AirportID") equals allAP.Field<int>("ID")                  
             select new 
             {
                Region = allAP.Field<string>("region")                    
             }                                
            );
```

and the second which gets me my result:

```
var join =
            (
                from table in query
                 group table by table["Region"] into groupedTable
                 select new
                 {
                     Key = groupedTable.Key,
                     Count = groupedTable.Count()
                 }
             );
```

not being an expert in Linq I converted the SharePoint lists into datatables so I could do the join.  Can I combine this into a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make two linq methods due to the fact that I did not want to try to method chain and do a groupby afterwards.  It just would of been too confusing.